Spark SQL Parsing Error While Schedule Trigger Data Bricks Pipeline
I am doing merge or query statement in my pyspark SQL and notebook executed perfectly when i run manually but if i schedule the pipeline in databricks workflow, i am getting below errors. kindly help me to provide your feedback.
dbutils.widgets.text("catalogname","test")
unity_catalog_name = dbutils.widgets.get("catalogname")
%sql
select * $catalogname.schema.tablename


error as below like when i execute in schedule pipeline
[PARSE_SYNTAX_ERROR] Syntax error at or near '.'. SQLSTATE: 42601


You are missing "from" in your select statement

its my mistake for while posting question . even if i put from also I am getting issues


You must use the SQL IDENTIFIER() clause to parse strings as object identifiers such names for databases, tables, views, functions, columns, and fields.

So, the according to above the new query with  IDENTIFIER() clause will look like below:

%sql

select  *  from IDENTIFIER(:catalogname ||  '.schema.tablename' )


My execution on schedule trigger is as below where you can see the pipeline launched by schedule trigger:


Note:  the error I am getting because I don't have such table in my databricks

